# How to get an AppScript variable and send it to JS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to get information that is in a cell (F3), and insert it into a JS variable.

I know that to send variables from JS to AppScript it is through `google.run.nomedafuncao()`

However, in this case, the meaning would be the opposite. Can anyone help me?

In my example I have a variable called `information = ss.getRange(6,3).getValue();`

I want to get the data from the AppScript variable 'information', and pass it to the JS variable called 'name'

I tried to send the information via JS, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a variable from App Script to the client use

```
let name = null;    
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( function(value) { name = value; } ).nomedafuncao();
```

Where `value` is returned from the server function `nomedafuncao()`.

Answer (score 0):

To get an Apps Script variable and send it to JavaScript, you can use the google.script.run API, which allows you to communicate between your Google Apps Script code and the client-side JavaScript code (HTML/JavaScript).